# How to sort by 2nd or third element, in prolog?

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

Here I have a naive_sort that sorts a list of lists by its first element. How would I go about changing it to sort by its second or third element?

```
 naive_sort(X,Sortedlist):-perm(X,Sortedlist),is_sorted(Sortedlist).

 is_sorted([]).
 is_sorted([_]).
 is_sorted([ [X | XT], [Y | YT] | T]) :- X < Y, is_sorted([ [Y | YT] | T]).

 takeout(Item, [Item | L], L).
 takeout(Item, [X | L], [X | L1]) :- takeout(Item, L, L1).

 perm([], []).
 perm([X | Y], Z) :- perm(Y, W), takeout(X, Z, W).
```

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If you know each list has at least 3 elements, the simplest thing to do would be to refer to the list as `[X, Y, Z|T]` and compare `Z` values.

Comment: thanks! How would I change the code I provided?

Comment: I'm leaving that as an exercise. Look at your `is_sorted([[X|XT], [Y|YT]|T])` predicate, in particular. Instead of `[X|XT]`, for example, which gives access to the first element, you need to access the 3rd element.